# Joining two time-series in same function

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, plyr, rbind

I'm trying to join two function results in one and trying to obtain results in one column.

My code

```
myfun <-function(x){
  fit <-Arima(x, order = c(1,1,1), seasonal = list(order = c(0,1,0), period = 52),include.mean=TRUE,
                        include.constant = FALSE, method = 'CSS')
    fit_a <- forecast(fit$fitted)
    fit_a <- data.frame(fit_a$fitted)
    colnames(fit_a)[1] <- "load"
    fit_a$load <- as.data.frame(fit_a$load)
    fit_b <- data.frame(forecast(fit,h=400))
    fit_b <- data.frame(fit_b$Point.Forecast)
    colnames(fit_b)[1] <- "load"
    fit_b$load <- as.data.frame(fit_b$load)
    return(rbind(fit_a,fit_b))
  }
```

I'm getting values individually like `return(fit_a)` and `return(fit_b)` but while doing rbind() I can't because of individual time-series data.
Tried : `c(fit_a,fit_b)` showing two different ts( which confirms we are having output and just failing over `rbind()`).

Can someone help me, how to extract both fitted and forecasted values in same function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: save them as different elements in a list and return the list?

Comment: @RAB Could you please explain me a bit more clear. I already have fit_a and fit_b as two different elements and trying to extract them by joining at last step.

Comment: yeah, so `fit <- list(fit_a, fit_b)` and `return(fit)`. Then `fit[[1]]` will be your `fit_a` and `fit[[2]]` will be your `fit_b`

Comment: added ans answer with a little more info for future people. feel free to mark as the answer if it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to return more than one object is to create a list of the objects, then return that. In your case you could use this at the end of your function:

```
fit <- list(fit_a, fit_b)

return(fit)
```

Then you can access the elements using `fit[[1]]` or `fit[[2]]`.

You also have the option of naming the elements so you can access them using the `$`, like so:

```
fit <- list(fit_a = fit_a, fit_b = fit_b)

return(fit)
```

Then you can use `fit$fit_a` and `fit$fit_b`